# sql openquery update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Cuando realizo un update de mysql dentro de un openquery sql-server este lo ignora. No registra ningun dato, en caso de que saque el where me tira un error inmediato.

¿ Que otra opción tengo o fallo ?

```
UPDATE sp
SET sp.numDoc = @numDoc, 
    sp.tipoDocId = @tipoNumDoc, 
    sp.nombreCompleto = @nombreCompleto, 
    sp.fechaNacimiento = @fechaNacimiento, 
    sp.correoElectronico = @correoElectronico, 
    sp.usuario = @usuario, 
    sp.clave = @clave
FROM openquery(mysql_servicioalclientedb,'select id, numDoc, tipoDocId, nombreCompleto, fechaNacimiento, correoElectronico, usuario, clave
    FROM servicioalclientedb.cliente
    WHERE servicioalclientedb.cliente.id=@id') sp
```

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionarlo:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(1)
            SELECT  @VAR = CONVERT(char(1),@id)
            SELECT  @TSQL = 'DELETE FROM OPENQUERY(mysql_servicioalclientedb,''SELECT * FROM telefonoxcuenta 
                             WHERE idCliente = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'
```